# Facebook doesn't display feature image from wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Recently I am facing a problems with one of my website. I have a website (http://www.sclrship.com) of wordpress that contain feature image and an image inside the post. But over last few days, I saw that while I try to post in facebook, it display **"Database Error"** instead of displaying image and description from post. For example if I want to share this link (http://www.sclrship.com/ias-sts-long-term-fellowship-programme-for-international-fellows-in-austria/) it will display Database Error.

On the other hand, if I share another post from shame website like (http://www.sclrship.com/eyes-high-doctoral-student-scholarship-for-international-students-at-university-of-calgary-in-canada-2015-2/), then it is displaying everything with image.

Any idea how to fixed this issue?

Comment: Use the facebook url debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to debug. When I tried with the url you have provided, it says multiple og:url values provided.

Comment: They are all working for me. Maybe they are cached for you? But use the debugger like menakas suggested, that tool is great for testing.

I did however notice your index page did not have an image attribute.

Comment: Well... thank you for both of your efforts. Its already fixed. Actually the problem was like as follows-

1. There was a option in theme to display OG data for post. It was on. I needed to be off that...

2. I was using NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster plugin, I needed to be inactive to make sure that OG Type is working properly. 


TQ for all of you...